# Lilo makes a lot of disk noise

Tags: linux, boot, lilo

After upgrading to Debian Wheezy, the `lilo` command causes my boot disk to make a lot of noise. I am not aways of any real problems, just the noise sounds somewhat scary, especially since this wasn't the case earlier.

When I run `lilo -v4` I can see that each noise corresponds with one of these lines:

```
Mapped AL=0x00 CX=0xbc27 DX=0xbee0, LBA=12500007
Mapped AL=0x00 CX=0xbc28 DX=0xbee0, LBA=12500008
Mapped AL=0x00 CX=0xbc29 DX=0xbee0, LBA=12500009
Mapped AL=0x00 CX=0xbc2a DX=0xbee0, LBA=12500010
Mapped AL=0x00 CX=0xbc2b DX=0xbee0, LBA=12500011
Mapped AL=0x00 CX=0xbc2c DX=0xbee0, LBA=12500012
```

there are 27779 such lines in the verbose output.

The noise does not sound unhealthy, more like a regular head movement. It sounds like for each of these lines lilo does a seek and the head happens to be in a distant position.

Does anybody know what might have caused the change from silent operation to noisy operation?

Comment: Maybe the `-v4`? Can you just omit that?

Comment: The -v4 was only to see what it is doing. The noise occurs with or witout it

Comment: What's your lilo.conf? Do you need to add an initrd-entry?

Comment: I don't use a ramdisk. Should I?

Comment: Not necessarily - if all drivers you need to mount `/` are built-in (they usually are when you are building custom kernel).

Comment: Try using the `compact` option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about lilo, but I can tell you how to figure out if the hard disk is OK. Use `smartctl` as root to query its status:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | less
```

In rare cases, the `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result` line will tell you whether your hard disk is failing, but in my experience, this predictive component of SMART seldom works. Instead, scroll down to the block beginning with `SMART Self-test log structure`; most probably, it will look like this:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]
```

If that is the case, you will need to start a self-test to figure out whether the hard disk is OK. This will take a few hours (depending on the hard disk size). Don't worry, it's non-destructive and it won't block the hard disk, so you can just run it in the background while the filesystem is mounted:

```
smartctl -t long /dev/sda
```

Wait until the test is finished (it will tell you how long it will take when you start it), and then re-query the SMART data:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | less
```

Now look at the self-test block. If it says "Completed without error", your hard disk is fine:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2262         -
```

If it reports an error, your hard disk is broken and you will need to backup your data immediately, if you haven't already done so. We're using this self-test feature on several thousand hard disks and so far it has been 100% reliable - if it says "Completed without error", the disk is definitely OK, and if it reports an error, it's definitely broken.